# Question on Purcell's derivation of electric fields caused by polarized matter

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

[image]

I don't understand how he obtained $dz\cos(θ)=-dr$. I've tried law of cosines but I keep getting expressions that won't simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Project the "bottom" of the vector $P$ to the radius $r+dr$, you get a right triangle whose hypothenuse is $|dz|$ and the other sides are $|dr|$ and $|r d\theta|$ with $|dz cos(\theta)| = |dr|$. Now take care of the overall sign by noting that the larger the $z$ the smaller the angle $\theta$ is.

Comment: Got it, thanks. And I was able to rationalize the overall sign by noting that a larger z gives a smaller r.